# how to use geturl function to custom page in php value in magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, phtml, geturl

```
<a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl(
                                      'mpquotesystem/sellerquote/quoteedit/id/404/', 
                                      ['_secure' => $block->getIsSecure()]
                                  );?>">
```

> I want to give number is dynamic
>
> echo $block->getUrl('mpquotesystem/sellerquote/quoteedit/id/404/', //404 -
>
> **here I want to give $id how I can do this**

Comment: do you have ` $id` on file ?

Comment: ss   i have  $block->getquoteid();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way

```
<a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl(
                                  'mpquotesystem/sellerquote/quoteedit', 
                                  ['id'=> $id,'_secure' => $block->getIsSecure()]
                              );?>">
```

Comment: yeah it's working..........